# Error when trying to present a Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

when trying to present a modal view controller programatically from my UITabBarController I am getting the following error: "Warning: Attempt to present xyzLoginViewController on xyzTabBarViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Code is as follows:

```
+ (void) openWithViewController:(UIViewController*) controller AndDelegate:(id) delegate
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LoginSignup" bundle:nil];
    xyzLoginViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"xyzLoginViewController"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    vc.delegate = delegate;
    [controller presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I've tried executing this from my app delegate, and also in the viewDidAppear: method of my tab bar controller however this hasn't helped.

I've looked at many similar questions and had no luck thus far.

Comment: You need to add it one of the tabBarController's views, not the tabBarController itself.

Comment: Your controller you are passing into the method hasn't been presented yet. You need to present that view controller and then execute the modal.

Answer (score 1):

```
Attempt to present xyzLoginViewController on xyzTabBarViewController
whose view is not in the window hierarchy
```

You should take that warning seriously and literally; it means exactly what it says. At the time you are making this call, the xyzTabBarViewController's view is not in your app's window anywhere. You've created this instance, but its view is not in the window. If there *is* an xyzTabBarViewController's view in the window, it must be a *different* xyzTabBarViewController's view.

It really all comes down to what `controller` is in the code that you showed. But since you didn't show where `controller` comes from, or what else you've done with it, there is no more to be said.